# sidebar nav with drawer?

Tags: reactjs, layout, navigation

I was wondering if anyone knew what it is called when you have a sidebar nav with a collapsible drawer and main panel layout? I see this pattern everywhere now I wanted to find a tutorial on how to implement it in react or electron but all the results I get are for some other type of sidebar. This pattern is used in desktop electron-based apps like slack, vs code and microsoft teams and web apps like jira use it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can use the Paper component in the the material ui framework.

[docs here](https://material-ui.com/components/paper/)

Comment: thanks but I want to create my own in React without any libraries.